# how to use php 5 global variables as function arguments?

Tags: php

I have a very very simple function:

```
function pro_echo ($type, $key) {
    echo $type[$key];
}
```

for example i want to run `pro_echo('$_POST', 'my_post_val')` and i expect `$_POST['my_post_val']` to be echo

but I encounter ''Illegal string offset'' error:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pro_echo('$_POST', 'my_post_val')
```

Your arguments are 2 strings because of the quotes around them. 
Try

```
pro_echo($_POST, 'my_post_val');
```

Comment: It's the same as `echo $_POST['my_post_val']`

Comment: Perfect Answer ♥

Answer (score 1):

I don't know **why** you need this function, but what you need here is **variable variable**:

```
function pro_echo ($type, $key) {
    echo ${$type}[$key];
}
// and call it: note NO `$`!
pro_echo ('_POST', 'foo');
pro_echo ('_GET', 'bar');
```

But I suppose it is better to use function as:

```
function pro_echo ($value) {
    echo $value; // modify echo as you need
}
// and call it:
pro_echo ($_POST['foo']);
pro_echo ($_GET['bar']);
```